# CERN Extract Array from TNTuple

Tags: arrays, root-framework

I'm using CERN's ROOT framework and having some trouble storing and retrieving simple arrays. It seems like my best bet is to use the TNTuple class, but I can't find a way to easily access the data stored inside a TNTuple in a number-by-number way. Really, what I'd like to do is use the TNTuple exactly the way I'd normally use an array of floats, or easily convert the TNTuple to an array of floats. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would instead recommend using an array class -TArrayF - very straight-forward.

[TArrayF](http://root.cern.ch/root/html/TArrayF.html)

Answer (score 0):

`TNtuple` exposes the individual columns via `GetArgs()`, e.g.

```
// make dummy ntuple with some data
TNtuple nt("nt", "", "a:b:c");
nt.Fill(0, 0, 0);
nt.Fill(1, 1, 1);

// show the data we have
nt.Scan();
************************************************
*    Row   *         a *         b *         c *
************************************************
*        0 *         0 *         0 *         0 *
*        1 *         1 *         1 *         1 *
************************************************
(Long64_t)2

for (int row = 0; row < nt.GetEntries(); ++row) {
    nt.GetEntry(row);

    // run through a, b, c
    for (int column = 0; nt.GetNvar(); ++column) {
      nt.GetArgs()[column];
    }
}
```